# Convert publishedAt (API TIME) into normal time

Tags: datetime, time, simpledateformat, date-format, java-time

1.Do I have to have two views in xml layout, one for time and one for date? but in the URL (when I read the information in JSON formatter publishedAt (has time and date)

2. So how do I convert the time stamp of JSON into normal time.

The time or date you can say is in this format 2020-01-09T14:50:58.000Z 
    Should I convert it when I am in my Adapter file or should I do it in the QueryUtils where I am creating and extracting things from JSON.

```
**My QueryUtils.java** 

 try {
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(bookJson);
            JSONArray newsArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("articles");

            for (int i = 0; i < newsArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject currentNews = newsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                /*JSONObject properties = currentNews.getJSONObject("articles");*/
                JSONObject newsSource = currentNews.getJSONObject("source");

                String title = currentNews.getString("title");
                String description = currentNews.getString("description");
                String url = currentNews.getString("url");
                /*String name = properties.getString("name");*/
                String name = newsSource.getString("name");
                String time = currentNews.getString("publishedAt");

                String image = currentNews.getString("urlToImage");





                News news = new News (title, description, url, name, time, image);
                newss.add(news);
```

**My Adapterjava file is**

```
             TextView dateView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
               dateView.setText(currentNews.getTime());
```

I want to display my time and date together can someone help please?

Comment: What XML layout are your talking about? Your Question is quite confusing and unfocused.

Comment: I want my time to be displayed 2020-06-11 15:00 or something

Comment: By xml view I mean. Do I have to create two views one for date and one for time and then in adapter do some work to display date and time on those views or simply create one view and convert the datetime format and display it on that one view

Answer (score 1):

## Data model versus presentation

Parse your input string `2020-01-09T14:50:58.000Z` immediately as a `Instant` object. The `Z` on the end means UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2020-01-09T14:50:58.000Z" ) ;
```

Store that `Instant` object in your data model.

When it comes to presentation in your user-interface, adjust the `Instant` (always in UTC) to the time zone expected/desired by the user.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Then let *java.time* automatically localize. Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms used in localizing. The `Locale` has nothing to do with the time zone.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

This has all been covered many times on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and taking the time. I am very new to all this and unfortunately I cant get this working because after writing all this code I dont know what I should pass in my textview.  I will look on stackoverflow more

Comment: For example if I want to to display the title text from json (i would write this in adapter currentNews.getTitle(); similary when I need the time I am writing currentNews.getTime() this displays my time in quite literal format  2020-01-09T14:50:58.000Z like this, I want the time and date to be displayed 2020- 06-11 15:00 I am sorry for wasting your time